# Do variables assigned to properties follow the behavior of that property?

Tags: objective-c, properties, autorelease

Looking for a little clarification on how Objective-C properties work when 'linked' to instance variables. My confusion stems from how you can set a property equal to a instance variable through the `@synthesize` directive, like...

```
@synthesize someProp = _someIVar;
```

Now, if my `someProp` is all like...

```
@property (retain,readonly) SomeClass* someProp
```

...will this...

```
-(id)initWithAutoreleasedInstanceOfSomeClass:(SomeClass*)thingThatIsAutoreleased {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
         _someIVar = thingThatIsAutoreleased;
    }
    return self;
}
```

... cause `thingThatIsAutoreleased` to be retained?

Tanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since it's readonly you won't have a setter but you can set the value by setting the internal member variable.  If you set the internal var, then you need to retain it.

```
_someIVar = [thingy retain];
```

Note that you can call via KVC and get the retain to trigger

```
[self setValue:myValue forKey:@"someProp"];
```

So, to answer your original question, No, you won't get automatic retain/release if you're setting the iVar directly.  You have to retain/release if you're manipulating the iVar.